# Why does my column gap get smaller when I increase the width of my container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-multicolumn-layout

I'm having a hard time understanding the logic behind the column gap in a multi-column layout. I have the following HTML/CSS in [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnpqyvs0/):

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">2</div>
</div>
```

```css
.flex-container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  columns: 120px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.flex-item {
  background: OliveDrab;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
}
```

You will notice that if you change the `width` of the container from 300px to 400px, the gap between the columns actually shrinks.

[image]

Why is it doing this? Is it possible to left-align the columns so they don't move around? [Fixed gap between CSS columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105384/fixed-gap-between-css-columns) may suggest that's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column layout is a bit tricky. If you read the specification related to `column-width` you can find:

> describes the optimal column width. The actual column width **may be wider** (to fill the available space), **or narrower** (only if the available space is smaller than the specified column width). <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-multicol-1/#propdef-column-width)</sup>

Remove the width from the elements and resize the container to notice this:

```css
.flex-container {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  columns: 120px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow:hidden;
  resize:horizontal;
}

.flex-item {
  background: OliveDrab;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">2</div>
</div>
```

You will notice that the gap is indeed fixed but the width of columns is changing.

You can find more details around the algorithm here: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-multicol-1/#pseudo-algorithm

---

A solution is to consider the use of CSS grid having fixed column width. The trick is to define the width of the grid column to be equal to the gap+width of column and you make you container fill all the columns (its width will be a multiplier of *gap+width of column*)

Resize the screen to see the  result:

```css
.container {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit,140px); /* 120 + 20 */
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: horizontal;
  border: 1px solid blue;

}

.flex-container {
  grid-column:1/-1;
  column-width: 120px;
  column-gap: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.flex-item {
  background: OliveDrab;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">1</div>
    <div class="flex-item">2</div>
    <div class="flex-item">3</div>
    <div class="flex-item">4</div>
    <div class="flex-item">5</div>
    <div class="flex-item">6</div>
    <div class="flex-item">7</div>
    <div class="flex-item">8</div>
    <div class="flex-item">9</div>
    <div class="flex-item">10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome!  I had to add a `overflow: hidden` to the items as workaround for a Firefox bug (detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7785711/2223706)).

Answer (score 3):

If  you don't specify a column-count (the second parameter to columns) then the system will work out the number of columns possible (i.e. it takes auto as the column-count parameter).

You have specified an 'ideal' column width of 120px and the actual items have a width less than that. Therefore the system reckons you can get 3 columns into the container of width 400px and lays out the first two accordingly.

Here's some info from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-width

> The column-width CSS property sets the ideal column width in a
> multi-column layout. The container will have as many columns as can
> fit without any of them having a width less than the column-width
> value. If the width of the container is narrower than the specified
> value, the single column's width will be smaller than the declared
> column width.

If you want to make sure there are just two columns then give the second parameter:

```
columns: 120px 2;
```

```css
.flex-container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  columns: 120px 2;
  padding: 10px;
}

.flex-item {
  background: OliveDrab;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the trick is that the column-width:120px isn't respected. It's only a min boundary used. The final width is bigger

Comment: @TemaniAfif - yes, thanks, though I'm not sure exactly of the definition of 'ideal' or 'minimum boundary'- it's described in MDN documentation as 'ideal' - perhaps that's the same as a min boundary?  I've added the link and quote in case of help to people.

Comment: Thanks!  That explains why the observed behavior.  In terms of specifying the number of columns, I can't do that because I want it to depend on the width, but I guess having fixed width columns and fixed gap, but flexible number of columns [is impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105384/fixed-gap-between-css-columns)?

Comment: @Garrett added a solution to my answer if intrested